# I am making a random nickname generator, how can I choose a word randomly from a file?

Tags: java, list

I am fairly new to Java, and I have a project that involves making a random nickname from a list of adjectives and nouns and then inserts them in between the given first and last names. I have searched everywhere (if I missed a question that is like mine, please link it and I will delete my post), and I can't find an answer that works with what I want to do.

The two files that the scanner reads are long lists of words that all have numbers before them. I want the scanner to print out a random adjective and a random noun from each respective list.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RandomNicknameGenerator
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        System.out.println("What is your first name?");
        firstName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your last name?");
        lastName = input.nextLine();

        File adjFile = new File("C:\\Users\\5010171\\Documents\\List 
        Folder\\AdjList.txt");
        Scanner fs = new Scanner(adjFile);
        while(fs.hasNextLine())
        {
        //not entirely sure what to put here
        }

        File nounFile = new File("C:\\Users\\5010171\\Documents\\List 
        Folder\\NounList.txt");
        Scanner fs2 = new Scanner(nounFile);
        while(fs2.hasNextLine())
        {
        //not entirely sure what to put here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't expect us to just complete your code. SO is to help us fix issues with your code, not to write code for you

Comment: I don't want anyone to finish my code, I just need help with what I can use to pick a random word, or to even point me in the right direction, as I said I'm fairly new so I don't know what to do. Sorry if I made it seem like I wanted someone to write the code for me.

Comment: From where I stand, you have two options and I'll present them here but leave the code writing up to you, as this would be a great learning experience :)

 1. Keep a counter going for each line you read; stop after a random number of lines and there's your word.
 2. Read in the entire file into a `List` of Strings. From there, you can randomly select an item from the `List`.

Comment: I would go for the second option, that way you are sure the random number (where to stop) you've chosen is not beyond the number of elements you can choose.